# apply gsub over a certain column in a list of data frames

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames -results1- where the data frames look like this (but with more rows)

```
              names coefficients
1        ..a15.pdf   1.27679608
2        ..a17.pdf   1.05090176
```

I want to remove the dots before the variables in column 'names', i.e. change "..a15.pdf" to "a15.pdf".
I tried, with no success, different variations of

```
results1<-lapply(results1, function(x) {gsub("^.{0,2}", "", lapply(x, "[", "names"));x})
```

First two data frames from the list:

```
dput(results1[c(1,2)])
list(structure(list(names = c("..a15.pdf", "..a17.pdf", "..a18.pdf", 
"..a21.pdf", "..a2TTT.pdf", "..a5.pdf", "..B11.pdf", "..B12.pdf", 
"..B13.pdf", "..B22.pdf", "..B24.pdf", "..B4.pdf", "..B7.pdf", 
"..B8.pdf", "..cw10-1.pdf", "..cw15-1TTT.pdf", "..cw17-1.pdf", 
"..cw18.pdf", "..cw3.pdf", "..cw4.pdf", "..cw7_1TTT.pdf", "..cw13-1.pdf"
), coefficients = c(1.27679607834331, 1.05090175857491, 1.51820192474905, 
2.30296037386815, 1.48568731934637, 0.493713103224402, 1.02705905465749, 
0.999747360884078, 2.40828101927852, 0.695152132033603, 2.1436001615064, 
2.25444037842867, 0.909773940025014, 1.14837173756827, -1.36323271003293, 
0.341428535787024, -0.786878348480425, 0.793720472787986, -1.57831038567642, 
0.277733503122777, -0.0364645818969112, -18.336668416705)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L)), structure(list(names = c("..a15.pdf", "..a17.pdf", "..a18.pdf", 
"..a21.pdf", "..a2TTT.pdf", "..a5.pdf", "..B11.pdf", "..B12.pdf", 
"..B13.pdf", "..B22.pdf", "..B24.pdf", "..B4.pdf", "..B7.pdf", 
"..B8.pdf", "..cw10-1.pdf", "..cw15-1TTT.pdf", "..cw17-1.pdf", 
"..cw18.pdf", "..cw3.pdf", "..cw4.pdf", "..cw7_1TTT.pdf", "..cw13-1.pdf"
), coefficients = c(2.096687569578, 2.19826038300833, 1.91814204277357, 
0.801448541154512, 2.16169560949165, 1.48585130705963, 0.95126061691997, 
1.93116618236938, 1.92555316191766, 1.00560861920225, 2.91129684208931, 
2.75687804718002, 1.31164431967781, 2.22449059765255, -1.22629519335285, 
1.31168579553008, -17.5786422399896, 1.25323523754693, -0.754445550651364, 
0.555577381430987, 0.577850999404076, -34.2662973287062)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with tidyverse

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

map(results1, ~.x[]%>% 
      mutate(names = str_replace_all(names,"\\.\\.", "")))

[[1]]
           names coefficients
1        a15.pdf   1.27679608
2        a17.pdf   1.05090176
3        a18.pdf   1.51820192
4        a21.pdf   2.30296037
5      a2TTT.pdf   1.48568732
6         a5.pdf   0.49371310
7        B11.pdf   1.02705905
8        B12.pdf   0.99974736
9        B13.pdf   2.40828102
10       B22.pdf   0.69515213
```

Comment: Pete, I am getting the following error: Error: `.x` must be a vector, not a function

Comment: you have to library `purrr`

Comment: Yes I did. This is the explanation I am getting: rlang::last_error()
<error/purrr_error_bad_type>
`.x` must be a vector, not a function
Backtrace:
 1. purrr::map(...)
 2. purrr:::stop_bad_type(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

Comment: rlang::last_trace()
<error/purrr_error_bad_type>
`.x` must be a vector, not a function
Backtrace:
    x
 1. +-purrr::map(...)
 2. \-purrr:::stop_bad_type(...)

Comment: are you sure you type `~.x` not `.x` ? also, my `df` is the dataframe loaded from your structure

Comment: I've copy pasted. Here is the text from console:  library(purrr)
>   library(dplyr)
>   library(stringr)
>   
>   map(df, ~.x[]%>% 
+         mutate(names = str_replace_all(names,"\\.\\.", "")))
Error: `.x` must be a vector, not a function
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: You `dataframe` should be yours, not `df`

Comment: I guess it is `results1` check my answer again

Comment: I have tested some of the proposed code to apply gsub over one column in the dataframes within the list and all of them convert all variables in the dataframes to character

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape `.` in `gsub` by using `\\` two backslashes.  This will replace all (any number of) dots preceeding the actual name.

```r
results <- list(structure(list(names = c("..a15.pdf", "..a17.pdf", "..a18.pdf", 
                                         "..a21.pdf", "..a2TTT.pdf", "..a5.pdf", "..B11.pdf", "..B12.pdf", 
                                         "..B13.pdf", "..B22.pdf", "..B24.pdf", "..B4.pdf", "..B7.pdf", 
                                         "..B8.pdf", "..cw10-1.pdf", "..cw15-1TTT.pdf", "..cw17-1.pdf", 
                                         "..cw18.pdf", "..cw3.pdf", "..cw4.pdf", "..cw7_1TTT.pdf", "..cw13-1.pdf"
), coefficients = c(1.27679607834331, 1.05090175857491, 1.51820192474905, 
                    2.30296037386815, 1.48568731934637, 0.493713103224402, 1.02705905465749, 
                    0.999747360884078, 2.40828101927852, 0.695152132033603, 2.1436001615064, 
                    2.25444037842867, 0.909773940025014, 1.14837173756827, -1.36323271003293, 
                    0.341428535787024, -0.786878348480425, 0.793720472787986, -1.57831038567642, 
                    0.277733503122777, -0.0364645818969112, -18.336668416705)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                    -22L)), structure(list(names = c("..a15.pdf", "..a17.pdf", "..a18.pdf", 
                                                                                                                                                     "..a21.pdf", "..a2TTT.pdf", "..a5.pdf", "..B11.pdf", "..B12.pdf", 
                                                                                                                                                     "..B13.pdf", "..B22.pdf", "..B24.pdf", "..B4.pdf", "..B7.pdf", 
                                                                                                                                                     "..B8.pdf", "..cw10-1.pdf", "..cw15-1TTT.pdf", "..cw17-1.pdf", 
                                                                                                                                                     "..cw18.pdf", "..cw3.pdf", "..cw4.pdf", "..cw7_1TTT.pdf", "..cw13-1.pdf"
                                                                                                                    ), coefficients = c(2.096687569578, 2.19826038300833, 1.91814204277357, 
                                                                                                                                        0.801448541154512, 2.16169560949165, 1.48585130705963, 0.95126061691997, 
                                                                                                                                        1.93116618236938, 1.92555316191766, 1.00560861920225, 2.91129684208931, 
                                                                                                                                        2.75687804718002, 1.31164431967781, 2.22449059765255, -1.22629519335285, 
                                                                                                                                        1.31168579553008, -17.5786422399896, 1.25323523754693, -0.754445550651364, 
                                                                                                                                        0.555577381430987, 0.577850999404076, -34.2662973287062)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       -22L)))
library(tidyverse)
results %>% map(~ .x %>% mutate(names = gsub('^\\.*(.*)$', '\\1', names)))
#> [[1]]
#>            names coefficients
#> 1        a15.pdf   1.27679608
#> 2        a17.pdf   1.05090176
#> 3        a18.pdf   1.51820192
#> 4        a21.pdf   2.30296037
#> 5      a2TTT.pdf   1.48568732
#> 6         a5.pdf   0.49371310
#> 7        B11.pdf   1.02705905
#> 8        B12.pdf   0.99974736
#> 9        B13.pdf   2.40828102
#> 10       B22.pdf   0.69515213
#> 11       B24.pdf   2.14360016
#> 12        B4.pdf   2.25444038
#> 13        B7.pdf   0.90977394
#> 14        B8.pdf   1.14837174
#> 15    cw10-1.pdf  -1.36323271
#> 16 cw15-1TTT.pdf   0.34142854
#> 17    cw17-1.pdf  -0.78687835
#> 18      cw18.pdf   0.79372047
#> 19       cw3.pdf  -1.57831039
#> 20       cw4.pdf   0.27773350
#> 21  cw7_1TTT.pdf  -0.03646458
#> 22    cw13-1.pdf -18.33666842
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>            names coefficients
#> 1        a15.pdf    2.0966876
#> 2        a17.pdf    2.1982604
#> 3        a18.pdf    1.9181420
#> 4        a21.pdf    0.8014485
#> 5      a2TTT.pdf    2.1616956
#> 6         a5.pdf    1.4858513
#> 7        B11.pdf    0.9512606
#> 8        B12.pdf    1.9311662
#> 9        B13.pdf    1.9255532
#> 10       B22.pdf    1.0056086
#> 11       B24.pdf    2.9112968
#> 12        B4.pdf    2.7568780
#> 13        B7.pdf    1.3116443
#> 14        B8.pdf    2.2244906
#> 15    cw10-1.pdf   -1.2262952
#> 16 cw15-1TTT.pdf    1.3116858
#> 17    cw17-1.pdf  -17.5786422
#> 18      cw18.pdf    1.2532352
#> 19       cw3.pdf   -0.7544456
#> 20       cw4.pdf    0.5555774
#> 21  cw7_1TTT.pdf    0.5778510
#> 22    cw13-1.pdf  -34.2662973
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
lapply(your_list, function(df) dplyr::mutate(df, column = gsub(x = column, pattern = "pattern", replacement = "replacement")))
```

your_list- the list containing dataframes

column- the variable inside the dataframes where you want to do the gsub

In this way I found that the code did not change the class of the other variables in my dataframes